# Set a Grid next to another in a gwt Page

Tags: css, gwt, grid, alignment

What kind of styling should I set to two Grids in order the one to stand next to the other? In the way I have created them in the xml file, the second stands below the other and it does not comply with the style of the general Page:

```
<div>
      <z:StaticDataGrid  ui:field="staticDataGrid" />
      <z:DataGrid ui:field="displayedDataGrid" />
</div>
```

StaticDataGrid and DataGrid are class representing Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Place the grids inside a HorizontalPanel to place them side by side.

```
<z:HorizontalPanel>
  <z:StaticDataGrid  ui:field="staticDataGrid" />
  <z:DataGrid ui:field="displayedDataGrid" />
</z:HorizontalPanel>
```

Comment: OK, it can be done with hPanel but it is imperative not to use one in this case.